# How to append/push a new object inside the array object in angular

Tags: javascript, typescript

how to append/push a new object in angular.

here's the data:

```
 data = [
     { title: 'Book1' },
     { title: 'Book2' },
     { title: 'Book3' },
     { title: 'Book4' }
    ]
```

What I want to do is to add inside the object like access.
expected output:

```
data = [
         { title: 'Book1', author: false },
         { title: 'Book2', author: false },
         { title: 'Book3', author: false },
         { title: 'Book4', author: false }
        ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the property using a map and object destructor in ES6

```
data = [
     { title: 'Book1' },
     { title: 'Book2' },
     { title: 'Book3' },
     { title: 'Book4' }
    ].map(d => ({ ...d, author: false }));
```

```js
let data = [
     { title: 'Book1' },
     { title: 'Book2' },
     { title: 'Book3' },
     { title: 'Book4' }
    ].map(d => ({ ...d, author: false }));
    
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Example :

```js
 data = [
     { title: 'Book1' },
     { title: 'Book2' },
     { title: 'Book3' },
     { title: 'Book4' }
    ]
    
    data.map(item => {
      item.author = false
    })
    console.log("Data",data)
```